# What is the equivalent of LESS's "import (reference) 'style'" in SASS

Tags: sass, less

In addition to application.css.scss, I have multiple partials like homepage.css.scss. At the moment I have to add @import 'bootstrap' to each one of them in order to use bootstrap variables and mixins.

Let's say I want to change my default links colour to red, I'd add that to application.css.scss. But the links in homepage.css.scss will not be red because the bootstrap import will override it with blue.

In LESS, I can do @import (reference) "bootstrap", how can I do that in SASS?

Comment: Are you working in rails ?

Comment: Yes. Rails 3.2 to be exact.

Answer (score 19):

The closest you will get is a *silent class / placeholder*. These work a little different to how LESS and *reference* work, you can read more on them here: http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/extending-placeholder-selectors-with-sass

**LESS**

*lib.less*

```
.class {
   background: red;
}
```

*main.less*

```
@import (reference) "lib";

.anotherClass {
   &:extend(.class);
}
```

**SASS**

*lib.sass*

```
%class {
  background: red;
}
```

*main.sass*

```
@import "lib";

.anotherClass {
  @extend %class;
}
```

**CSS Output**

```
.anotherClass {
  background: red;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about the silent class. The problem is I'm using Bootstrap and I'd need to modify the its classes to silent classes. I still don't believe this is not a widespread problem for lots of Rails apps since SASS is the default in there.

Comment: @chh sadly you would. I would take a look at making custom css selectors more specific than the bootstrap ones, which would also solve your issue.

Comment: its incredible that they havent implemented this after 6 years of having this problem. I wonder why