# How to import specified classes from CSS file instead of everything

Tags: css, sass, less

I'm trying to import **some** classes from a **CSS** file like bootstrap.css to my site.scss **SASS** file, not **all** of them. The problem with following code is that I get all bootstrap classes in my compiled site.css file:

**site.scss**

```
@import "bootstrap";

.my-div-md-6
{
    /*some other styles*/
    @extend .col-md-6;
}
```

On the other hand, It is possible to do this with **LESS** by importing bootstrap.css as **reference** using this code:

**site.less**

```
@import (less, reference) "bootstrap.css";

.my-div-md-6{
     /*some other styles*/
    &:extend(.col-md-6);
}
```

The compiled output of **LESS** is very light as below:

**site.css**

```
.my-div-md-6 {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 1px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
}
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .my-div-md-6 {
    float: left;
  }
  .my-div-md-6 {
    width: 50%;
  }
}
.my-div-md-6 {
  /*some other styles*/
}
```

Is it possible to achieve this with SASS? If yes, giving a quick example would help.

Comment: And does [a customized version](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/) not provide you with what you would need?

Comment: Bootstrap was and example, my question domain can be any css file.
I've tagged bootstrap because most bootstrap users play with less and sass.

Comment: i don't think you can natively within SASS; the documentation doesn't seem to specifically say, however I do believe that, looking into wrappers around sass may be able to do that (what task runner are you using? grunt/webpack/gulp, some other thing?)

Comment: looking into this more, the feature you mention is `import reference` which is bit of a new concept for me using scss. There appears to be `silent classes` [what-is-the-equivalent-of-lesss-import-reference-style-in-sass](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22860954/2903169) and also it seems to be a pending feature within the sass git repository [issue](https://github.com/sass/sass/issues/1094)

Comment: @Denis Do you mean mixins or sth like by wrappers?? I'm currently using web compiler in visual studio,  but no matter if any other task runner do this.

Comment: @efe, i was thinking if there was something, like in webpack that reads the `sass` file for `reference` and then converts that reference into something appropriate.... otherwise you might have to use `un-css` or `post-css` if there isn't any available tool for you there

Comment: @Denis Your link is a nice answer that i checked before posing this question. I used placeholders that extend a css class from external file, but the compiled result was the same, containing whole classes.

Comment: give me a minute -i'm reading the github sass import feature request (linked before)

Comment: @Denis Thanks for your attention. I'm also reading about un-css and post-css.

Comment: @Efe
[CSS modules](https://github.com/css-modules/css-modules#dependencies) might help


[REF:](https://github.com/sass/sass/issues/1094#issuecomment-143879618)

Comment: looks like native ruby sass has been wanting/discussing this feature for a while, (over 4 years) especially with talk about sass4, but nothing substantial (wouldn't hold my breath)

for quick solution - i'd use POSTCSS/UNCSS to clean your css output (another build step unfortunately)... diving deeper

Comment: @Denis That's really cool. I'm just surprised by react.js(haven't been around this). But there is a problem here for me. With this solution, I need to send x.css(which I don't need classes) to client, in which there will be performance issues like file size to load for client. Am I right?

Comment: @efe 
TLDR;
**ADVISE: USE ALTERNATIVE METHODS than native Sass**

so firstly, you need to cut the unused css that's been generated by sass (because there's no import reference) Have been digging around and since `nex3` - the author of `sass` has been working on `google dart` - they have begun migrating sass from `ruby` to `dart` hence the slow updates in features. I assume that due to this, future releases may be tied to the `dart/sass` release and there is some uncertainty of native ruby support.

Comment: @Denis WOW! bad luck. you are a good researcher and seems you really need this feature of sass more than I do!! One more question. Does POST/UNCSS effect media queries? suppose that I want to import some of bootstrap(an example css file with mediaqueries) to my sass and avoid sending bootstrap to client(totally removing any CDN of bootstrap.css in my pages). Since media queries are not explicitly referenced but used for resonsive design, will uncss recognize this and keep media queries? Something like smart dependency walking.

Comment: @Efe
UNCSS will remove unused css, and without the media option, will remove the media query (there's a media query option in uncss to retain the styles) 

REF: [SO ANSWER](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33938248/2903169)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139398/discussion-between-denis-tsoi-and-efe).

Comment: @Den Did you find alternatives to UNCSS? Sass seems to still not include that feature

Comment: ehhh this question is like 3 years old - im unsure if you're facing the same issue or something different, you might want to ask a new question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is not simple answer and at the time of writing this, `Ruby Sass` does not natively support the LESS `import (reference)` feature.

---

**TLDR; Suggestions:**

- use **uncss or postcss** to remove the compiled css from file before finalising stylesheet.
- if you can, use mixins and placeholder classes as a rewrite of the scss file, but this is the **MOST** time consuming.
- <s>`import "file"` as partial such that `file="_file.scss"` and `@extend .class` if you absolutely have to, (manual method but suppose it'll work)</s>

---

**UNCSS**

You can use uncss as a package from `npm` to remove the compiled css (I know this isn't efficient, but if you **had** to use `SASS`), then you'd remove the chaff that's generated from the example bootstrap import.

**HOW?**
QUOTE: [SO-Answer-Joesph](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33938248/2903169)

> How? The process by which UnCSS removes the unused rules is as follows:
>
> - The HTML files are loaded by PhantomJS and JavaScript is executed.
> - Used stylesheets are extracted from the resulting HTML.
> - The stylesheets are concatenated and the rules are parsed by css-parse.
> - `document.querySelector` filters out selectors that are not found in the HTML files.
> - The remaining rules are converted back to CSS.
>
> So yes, it removes selectors not in the DOM at runtime. If you have dynamically added selectors, you can make uncss ignore them by commenting: /* uncss:ignore */ before them, e.g...

**MAKE SURE YOU ADD THE MEDIA OPTION IN UNCSS**
REF: [SO-Answer-Deksden](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38090903/2903169)

---

**SASS Background research:**
*Summarising above:*

`nex3`: one of the core leads for sass, has been at `google` and working on `dart`. They released `dart-sass` (unstable release) as a rewrite in favour to replace and improve upon `ruby sass`. This is interesting as this rewrite also explains the lack of feature development in `Ruby Sass` as well as the need for a rewrite. Since a core contributor of a ruby sass port: i.e. *libsass* (C++ implementation of ruby-sass) left the libsass team, it brings a further impetus to improve on sass performance.

Credit:

- [Joesph](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33938248/2903169)
- [Deksden](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38090903/2903169)